# Replacing obj-c app with totally new rewrite in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store

I want to replace an existing obj-c app with one written in Xamarin. I figure I just need to use the same bundle id in the rewrite and I should be fine.

There is a local database and images involved that need to be used.

I'm concerned because we have an internal app store at the company and users are not able to install over the app store app and I'm not getting details as to why.

I do know that I'm not using an app store provisioning profile in our enterprise app store, so that might be why.

For the enterprise app store, I'm using an AdHoc release provisioning profile.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Differences:**

1. **App Store provisioning profile** is for uploading to the Apple App Store. If you want to submit your app to the app store of Apple. You have to use app store provisioning profile.
2. [**Apple Developer Enterprise Program**](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) is for company or enterprise to distribute internal apps. If you want to distribute a release version, use the `In-house` provisioning profile of it, not the `Ad-Hoc`. Because, `In-house` has no device number limitation, but `Ad-Hoc` has (100 only).

**Notices:**

1. Usually, we use OTA to distribute an In-house app. I think your company app store use it too. So, the users can install it via Wifi.
2. If there's a same bundle identifier app from Apple App Store on the device, sometimes your enterprise app will not install on that device. You have to remove the app which is from Apple App Store, then install yours. But, there's no official documentation from Apple to explain this case.

**Summary:**

**If you want users to install your app from Apple App Store app, use the app store provisioning profile. Otherwise, use the `In-House` provisioning profile to distribute it via enterprise app store.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't install an enterprise app over an appstore app or vice versa with the same bundle identifier. You run into the same issue if you install an enterprise app on a device and then try to debug that same app. It will give you an error. I think it's something like an internal inconsistency error. If you connect a device and look at the console log while it's installing, you should see some error along those lines and if you google it, you'll see that it won't allow you to install the same app with different profiles.

Answer (score 1):

To install a development or Ad Hoc app over an iOS App Store app with the same bundle identifier (suffix), the user has to first delete the App Store app from the device, before installing the Ad Hoc app.